# problem with lazy loading in nested child routing , angular. Cannot access to the view

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: { breadcrumbs: 'Home' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'configurazione',
        data: { breadcrumbs: 'configurazione' },
        component: ConfigurazioniComponent,
        children : [
          {
            path:'protocollo',
            loadChildren:()=>import("./modules/protocollo/protocollo.module").then(
              (m)=>m.ProtocolloModule
            ),
          }
        ]
      }]
```

From this code i cannot load the ProtocolloModule. When from the route i write "configurazione/protocollo" i get stucked in the path "configurazione". How can i solve this?
If i insert loadModule out of the second child all work great.How can i make it work in this way?

Comment: can u post also the routes of ur ProtocolloModule ? take a look at the doc may helps https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
        component: ProtocolloGestioneComponent,
        data: { breadcrumbs: 'Protocollo' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'crea',
        component: ProtocolloCensimentoSidenavComponent,
        canDeactivate : [CanDeactivateGuard]
      }
    ],  
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProtocolloRoutingModule { }
```

This is the routing of the protocol, i cant understand what's missing or that i didn't put yet fot make it work in a nested way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.
There was no  in the Component configurations template. Now I have another problem, in configurations / protocol I have both the configuration template and the protocol template, as if the directive does not switch from view